# Cassandra: Get equivalent Java Class for DataType

Tags: java, cassandra, key-value-store

It seems that in the 2.2. version of the Java driver, in DataType, the method "asJavaClass()" from previous versions was removed. Does anyone have any idea how to get the equivalent Java Class for a given DataType.

thanks in advance

Altober

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the introduction of custom codecs in 2.2, there is no pre-established mapping to a given Java class, that would depend on the codecs that are registered and which getter method you call to retrieve the value. At best we could provide the "default" mapping produced by the built-in codecs. What use case do you need this for?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I am using row.get(int i, Class<?> clazz), which I am interpreting according to the list here: http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.0/java-driver/reference/javaClass2Cql3Datatypes_r.html Basically, given a row I need to know which types are stored there and interpret them in terms of Java classes.

Comment: I think getObject(i) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes but then I cannot dynamically know the subtype of the Object right? unless I check every possible type or use reflection right?

Comment: Well you can do `object.getClass()` and use that to do whatever you were doing with the result of `asJavaClass()`. It's almost the same (except for collections where it will be an implementation, e.g. ArrayList instead of List).

Comment: Let me ask you a related question: What does it imply that there is no pre-established mapping, that I do not have to worry about the type of the input data? For instance, can I have a byte[] key without wrapping it into a ByteBuffer? E.g., Would this work?  session.execute(boundStatement.bind(key)); key is of type byte[].